# Async/Await with map or foreach

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to retrieve a bunch of product prices from my database and assumed I could just map, or foreach, through them and += the price onto a variable as below:

```
// Get Total
exports.getTotal = (req,res) => {
  let productList = req.body;
  let total = 0;

  const results = productList.map(async (product) => {
      Product.findById(product._id)
          .select('price')
          .exec((err, foundProduct) => {
              if (err){
                  console.log(`Error: Product with id ${product._id} not found.`);
              } else {
                  console.log('Product price. ', foundProduct.price);
                  total += foundProduct;
              }
          })
  });

  Promise.all(results).then(data => console.log('Total is', total));

};
```

However the console.log for the total always returns 0. I suspect it's an issue that the console.log is running before the map and database lookup promise has complete.

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Array's `map()` and `foreach()` methods do not use promises so making the callbacks `async` does not make the internal iteration wait before the doing the next iteration call to the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using exec in a wrong way Exec returns you a promise. You can simplify this like

```
// Get Total
exports.getTotal = (req, res) => {
  const productList = req.body;
  let total = 0;

  const results = productList.map(async product => {
    const foundProduct = await Product.findById(product._id).exec();
    total += foundProduct;
    return foundProduct;
  });

  Promise.all(results).then(data => console.log("Total is", total));
};
```

Comment: cool. feel free to mark the question as answered for other people's reference.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to await an asynchronous function `await Product.findById(product._id)`.

Also writing in a functional way removes clutter for this kind of task by using [array reduce.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
// Get Total
exports.getTotal = (req, res) => {
  const results = req.body.reduce(async (total, product) => {
    await Product.findById(product._id)
      .select('price')
      .exec((err, foundProduct) => {
        if (err){
          console.log(`Error: Product with id ${product._id} not found.`);
          return total
        } else {
          console.log('Product price. ', foundProduct.price);
          return total += foundProduct;
        }
      })
  }, 0);

  Promise.all(results).then(data => console.log('Total is', data));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Array's `map()`, `foreach()` and other iteration methods do not use promises. So making the callbacks `async` does not make the internal iteration wait before the doing the next iteration call to the callback. Also your map would have been filled with promises that never get resolved as you never return anything, it would be equivalent to having

```
Promises.all([new Promise(), new Promise(), new Promise()])
```

You can change your code to create a proper map of new promises and then calculate the total after everything has been fetched. Note since `exec()` itself returns a promise you just return that:

```
const results = productList.map(product=> {
  return Product.findById(product._id).select('price').exec();
});
Promise.all(results).then(values => {
  let total = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  console.log(`Total: ${total}`)
});
```

You could also just use a for loop in a standalone `async` function and use `await`

```
async function getTotal(){
  let total = 0;
  for(let product of productList){
    let price = await Product.findById(product._id).select('price').exec();
    total+=price;
  }
  return total;
}

getTotal().then(total=>console.log(`Total: ${total}`));
```